# sass @use directive and mobile first approach

Tags: sass

Recently I migrated a project to dartsass directive @use instead of @import.

I understood the main goal of @use directive but I think I missing something.

@use rule must come before any other rules... so I can't add a sass file at the end of main style.scss

In this way I can't apply the mobile first approach... Normally I write all mobile rules in main file and then, at the end of it, include the media query rules.

With @use directive I can't achive this. So for media-query scss I need to use @import in mainstyle.scss

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think that the only way is to transform the main file with css rules in another included file with @use directive and leave the main file as "container" of all components.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `@import`. Though it says it's going to be depricated, it is still perfectly fine to use it.
But you might generally concidere to switch to a more modular file structure, when it comes to your Sass projects. For example:

```
/root
  _desktop.scss
  _mobile.scss
  main.scss

// main.scss
@use (@import) "desktop";
@use (@import) "mobile";
```

Comment: I think you are right.

With @use is better to swtich to a modular structure. thank you